# Деструктор объекта

Tags: ооп, javascript

В php есть вот такая штука- `_destruct()` - это метод, который автоматически вызывается при удалении объекта. Есть возможность вызывать каждый раз определенную функцию при каждом удалении объекта на **javascript**? Что-то не получается удалить весь объект, а только свойства его.

```
function Apple() {
    var self = this;
    this.name = 'beluy_naliv';
    this._destruct = function () {
        delete self.name;
    }
    this._destruct2 = function () {
        delete self;
    }
}

obj = new Apple;
obj._destruct();
alert(obj.name); //удалило
obj._destruct2() //не удаляет
for (var j in obj) {
    document.write(j);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чистой, полноценно работающей модели, которая реализовывала-бы вашу задачу - нет, основная причина в производительности, GC должен работать как можно быстрее, в идеале моментально, вызов обработчиков перед очисткой, мягко говоря, этому не способствуют.

Представьте на секунду, допустим вы пишите какой-то ParticleSystem, у вас есть некий обработчик деструктора "класса" Particle, допустим вы уже создали 10000 экземпляров и теперь, допустим, в них нет необходимости и вы их "очищаете", таким образом, `время очистки теперь = (GCTime + destructorHandler) * 10000`, что, мягко говоря, не есть хорошо, к тому-же, такой подход сильно усложнял-бы отладку, оценку производительности приложения, да и вообще, банально - очевидность, как говориться - keep it simple.

Но, как уже справедливо подметили - вы можете реализовать **подобный** функционал сами, но - он не будет на прямую связан с работой GC, лишь с "очисткой" на уровне вашего кода, что, мягко говоря, не одно и тоже.

Comment: Да спасибо.Не подскажешь а в PHP он работает быстро?

Comment: @koza4ok настоятельно рекомендую отказаться от их использования, причины примерно такие-же, только еще, плюс ко всему, усугубляются печальностью схемы apache+php и, собственно, не редко, печальностью реализации самого php. На крайний случай используйте `observer` с рассылкой события `removed` или что-то в таком духе.

Comment: Вообще, только сейчас посмотрел ваш код и на ваши потуги, так вот

- почитайте о ООП в JS, по хорошему, такой код, в 99% случаев, нужно избегать ( да, исключения существуют =\ )
- не пытайтесь как-то вмешаться в работу JS GC, как минимум не на клиенте( у вас нет никаких прямых инструментов для этого, проще говоря - нельзя :) )
- Если у вас проблемы с памятью, то ваш код течет, то, что вы пытаетесь сделать вам не поможет
- Если объект вам просто больше не нужен и вы хотите показать это в коде, просто об**null**ите его
- если хотите низкоуровневой работы с памятью, то вы выбрали не тот язык

Comment: btw - не надо смешивать, по сути, 2 разных вопроса в 1, сначала вы спросили о

 > метод, который автоматически вызывается при удалении объекта

и дальше

 >  Что-то не получается удалить весь объект,а только свойства его

не порядок :)

Comment: Да потихоньку читаю ОП.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я знаю нет такого метода в js который бы был похож на деструктор c++, php или python. Но можно сделать его самому (вроде деструктор есть в dojo), просто добавь метод своему базовому объекту, который будет удалять этот объект. А при наследовании(прототипировании) просто делаешь такой же метод, выполняешь в нем те действия которые тебе нужны в деструкторе, а в конце вызываешь метод из прототипа. Ну и конечно придется отказаться от delete а использовать в замен его свой метод.

Comment: в `backbone` нет ничего подобного, да там есть `destroy` у моделей, но он только удаляет данные на сервере, да есть `dispose` у въюх, но он отписывает въюху от событий модели.

Comment: Да ты прав. Видимо у меня был самопальный деструктор.

Comment: Да спасибо,попробую.Не вспомнишь где такого  начитался?

Comment: Сложно сказать, но "JavaScript: сильные стороны" - тебе стоит точно прочитать. Многое проясняет, все кого я встречал и кто программируют на js говорят что это отличная книга.

Answer (score 1):

У javascript свой сборщик мусора, который сам удаляет объекты, когда решает, что они больше не используются (исчезает последняя ссылка на объект).Если нужен явный деструктор, то можно удалить почти все свойства у объекта ручками, создав свою функцию. Почитать [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120192/).

Comment: тут немного не о том

Comment: Я не совсем понял Вас,но хорошая идея насчет создания своей функции,которая будет все необходимое делать.Нужно пошаманить